# What is the "vendor" directory in a github repo?

Tags: github, vendor

I have seen a directory/folder called vendor in the root on some of GitHub repositories.

- What is the purpose of the vendor folder?
- What does revendoring mean?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: the `vendor` directory is created by `composer` which is a dependency manager for PHP - https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: Here, quick search for "javascript vendor directory" yielded [this](https://tommcfarlin.com/the-vendor-directory/)

Comment: @user202729 Questions about tools commonly used by programmers are on-topic. As such, questions about GitHub and git are on-topic here. This is, however, not relevant to JavaScript and is otherwise low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

I think `vendor`is a dependencies folder for `composer` project in PHP. Like the `node_modules` in Node.js projects